Каким пунктуационным правилом обусловлена постановка запятой с тире?
Наткнулся на следующее предложение у Достоевского (Бедные люди):
"Ведь надобно же вам их было, - я от Федоры узнал."
У Розенталя не нашел похожих по структуре примеров, к сожалению, но если попытаться немного изменить пунктуацию, то что мы имеем:
"Ведь надобно же вам их было, я от Федоры узнал."
"Ведь надобно же вам их было - я от Федоры узнал."
Оба варианта в моих глазах выглядят какими-то неполными, или даже неточными с точки зрения интонации/логичности.
Первое мое предположение, что тире здесь именно интонационное, но кажется, что всё таки дело не в этом.
Второе предположение заключается в том, что вторая часть - это своего рода комментарий относительно первой части предложения, и там как бы напрашивается слово "это" в самом начале, по типу:
"Ведь надобно же вам их было, - это я от Федоры узнал."
Возможно, я что-то (очевидное) упустил в своей мыслительной цепочке, поэтому очень интересно было бы послушать ваше мнение относительно данного вопроса. ^^

Похоже на то, что всё же в данном случае у Розенталя кое-что нашлось на этот счёт - запятая и тире в БСП, но лишь с тем замечанием, что в моем примере слово "вот" или "это" как бы опускается, но подразумевается ...
